# Django on Windows Server using mod_wsgi. No module named 'lxml.etree'

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a new Django project to a local Windows server via Apache with two preexisting Django projects. The site works when running locally on the server, but not via WSGI. I am using the mailmerge package to manipulate some docx templates, and when the site loads, it fails on the line "from lxml.etree import Element".

I have tried modifying the import command in the mailmerge.py file to no avail. I have installed the lxml and mailmerge packages in and outside of my virtualenv. I've googled and searched this and other sites, but the search results either don't apply or didn't solve the issue when I tried the various fix actions.

Here is a snippet from my Apache error log for the project:

[Apache Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAlGk.png)

Here is my wsgi_windows.py file:

```
# execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('D:/QR/qr_env/Lib/site-packages')




# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.insert(0,'D:/QR')
sys.path.insert(1,'D:/QR/quality_review')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'quality_review.settings'
#os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "quality_review.settings")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "quality_review.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application
```

This is the project's entry in the vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
    ServerName ********** 
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "logs/quality_review.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/quality_review.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "D:\QR\quality_review\wsgi_windows.py"
    <Directory "D:\QR\quality_review">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "D:\QR\static"
    <Directory "D:\QR\static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
    Alias /documents "D:\QR\documents"
    <Directory "D:\QR\documents">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf:

```
LoadFile "c:/users/rcs/appdata/local/programs/python/python37-32/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/rcs/appdata/local/programs/python/python37-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/rcs/appdata/local/programs/python/python37-32"
```

Here is the latest snippet from the main Apache error log:

```
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.550356 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 480:tid 560] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.550356 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(430): AH00402: Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.878480 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(1719): AH00453: Child process is running
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.878480 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 5412:tid 460] mod_wsgi (pid=5412): Python home c:/users/rcs/appdata/local/programs/python/python37.
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.878480 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 5412:tid 460] mod_wsgi (pid=5412): Initializing Python.
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.894105 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 5412:tid 460] mod_wsgi (pid=5412): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 5412:tid 460] mod_wsgi (pid=5412): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(344): AH00391: Child: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(513): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 424 (0.0.0.0:8082) and sending it to child process 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(466): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket 0.0.0.0:8082
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(513): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 420 ([::]:8082) and sending it to child process 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(513): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 416 (0.0.0.0:8081) and sending it to child process 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(513): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 412 ([::]:8081) and sending it to child process 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(513): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 400 (0.0.0.0:8080) and sending it to child process 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(513): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 408 ([::]:8080) and sending it to child process 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 480:tid 560] mpm_winnt.c(532): AH00411: Parent: Sent 6 listeners to child 5412
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(466): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket [::]:8082
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(466): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket 0.0.0.0:8081
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(466): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket [::]:8081
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(466): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket 0.0.0.0:8080
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(466): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket [::]:8080
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] mpm_winnt.c(491): AH00407: Child: retrieved 6 listeners from parent
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 460] child.c(969): AH00352: Child: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5412:tid 460] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 1172] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on 0.0.0.0:8082 using AcceptFilter connect
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 1180] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 using AcceptFilter connect
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 1192] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:8080 using AcceptFilter connect
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 1208] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:8081 using AcceptFilter connect
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 1204] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on 0.0.0.0:8081 using AcceptFilter connect
[Wed Jun 10 12:00:56.909730 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5412:tid 1212] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:8082 using AcceptFilter connect
```

I'm not sure what other information will be needed to help, but I'm happy to provide additional files if needed.

Comment: please share the similare lines from your apache.conf LoadFile "***ython37.dll" and LoadModule wsgi_module "***\mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"

Comment: I have edited my post with the requested information. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: your windows system is 32bits?

Comment: No, it's 64 bit Windows.

Comment: you've installed a 32bits version of python37: /mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall 32bits python37 version et re-install 64bits python37 version and update your apache conf:

```
LoadFile "***/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "*****/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
```

and then If you have any error, please share all the apache log file

please, in your httpd.conf file: set:

```
LogLevel debug
```

and look at your log file, can you find this information:

```
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.230167 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5560:tid 540] AH00455: Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.231163 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5560:tid 540] AH00456: **Apache Lounge VS16 Server built**: Apr 21 2020 16:23:13
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.231163 2020] [core:notice] [pid 5560:tid 540] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.231163 2020] [core:debug] [pid 5560:tid 540] log.c(1568): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: no (0)
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.232165 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5560:tid 540] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2860
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.232165 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 5560:tid 540] mpm_winnt.c(430): AH00402: Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.561181 2020] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 2860:tid 180] mpm_winnt.c(1719): AH00453: Child process is running
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.561181 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2860:tid 180] **mod_wsgi (pid=2860): Python home c:/program files/python37.**
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.561181 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2860:tid 180] m**od_wsgi (pid=2860): Initializing Python.**
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.584179 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2860:tid 180] **mod_wsgi (pid=2860): Attach interpreter ''.**
[Fri May 08 17:49:52.588181 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2860:tid 180] **mod_wsgi (pid=2860): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.**
```

and for WSGIPythonHome:

**"Used to indicate to Python when it is initialised where its library files are installed."**

I think you project site-pakages are in :

Comment: I have replaced the 32 bit python and Apache with 64 bit. My original two sites work after configuring Apache, but the newest site still gives the same module not found error. Here is the error log: [link](https://collierinc1-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jmelton_collierinc_com/EeeS4AdZMotAr5jYW_4gO7MBbFi8a7TADh_lrAp6J_EXJQ?e=lQdmhp)

Comment: Sorry, what paths do you mean?

Comment: I do not find in the log the messages of apache's starting

Comment: paths of httpd.conf:

Comment: Apache is starting, and is successfully serving the other sites. It only fails to load the site in question. The paths in httpd.conf are the paths I get from mod_wsgi, so I believe they're correct.

Comment: I updated my answer, It seems that apache searches for project packages in the system (where python is installed) and not in the project directory

Comment: I updated my original post with the error log to capture the information requested. If I change WSGIPythonHome or attempt to add a second path, Apache fails to start.

Comment: If you want and if it is possible you can  install all your project packages in your system same as python: "c:/users/rcs/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages

Comment: Installing the packages in the main system python directory solved the issue. Apparently I wasn't loading from the virtualenv for some reason. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: It is not the best solution, but it is fast. Very happy that was usufal. Can you please mark the question as answerd

Comment: I restarted the Apache service and now I'm getting the error again.

Comment: Change all apache and wgi configuration paths to tne new system site-package. And now you don't need the first line of wsgi.py: "activate this"